# Dictionary Of (String,Object) Serialization

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm trying to code a wcf service , for now Object serialization works fine . But i have to get a lot of Employees from my db , put them into a dictionary and then serialize it to send it to the client.
Well i user Newsoft Jsonnet to do this but it doesn't work . Do i have to use a dataset instead of Dictionary?

```
Public Function Get_All_Employee() As String Implements IService.Get_All_Employee
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT * From employee"
    Dim _Employe As Employe
    Try
        mysql_connection.Open()
        Dim sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, mysql_connection)
        Dim sqlreader As MySqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
        While sqlreader.Read()

            _Employe = New Employe()
            _Employe.id = sqlreader.Item("Id_Employee").ToString()
            _Employe.nom = sqlreader.Item("Nom").ToString()
            _Employe.prenom = sqlreader.Item("Prenom").ToString()
            _Employe.Mail = sqlreader.Item("Mail").ToString()
            _Employe.FonctionId = sqlreader.Item("Id_Fonction").ToString()

            If Not Employee_Dictionary.ContainsKey(_Employe.id) Then
                Employee_Dictionary.Add(_Employe.id, _Employe)
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Employee_Dictionary, Formatting.Indented)
End Function
```

**EDIT :**

I used Dataset instead of Dictionary and it worked as it should !

```
Public Function Get_All_Employee() As String Implements IService.Get_All_Employee
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT * From employee"
    Dim employe_dataset As DataSet = New DataSet
    Try
        mysql_connection.Open()

        Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(Query, mysql_connection)

        sqladapter.Fill(employe_dataset, "employee")

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employe_dataset, Formatting.Indented)
End Function
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" as in you get some kind of exception? You get wrong data?

Comment: Is your class _Employee marked as serializable? Anything _Employee references must also be serializable.

Comment: @Magnus i'm getting a null reference exception in the client wich means the server is sending an empty string . So from this i can conclude that the dictionary is empty . but i don't get why would it be empty .

Comment: @Trevor Yes it is marked as serializable , and when i serialize the employe object , this does work.